# no delete option to delete .bash_profile.swp

Tags: vim

I was editing a .bash_profile file and then I accidentally closed the bash console. since then whenever I try to open the .bash_profile using vim, I get E325: Attention error.

I went through a question which is similar to this and there's an answer where it's said to choose (D)elete among the options that are given. but I dont see that option.

```
While opening file "/Users/hareentej22/.bash_profile"
             dated: Fri May 18 02:20:07 2018

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r /Users/hareentej22/.bash_prof
ile"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file "/Users/hareentej22/.bash_prof
ile.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file "~/.bash_profile.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

Is there any otherway to solve this?

Answer (score 9):

The delete option is shown in newer version of vim but even newer version also sometimes does not show the option. I don't know under what conditions it shows.

I think `\rm ~/.bash_profile.swp` is the best way here